# MediaWiki: Implement HotCat

Tags: mediawiki

I found no literature on how to install HotCat category management tool in MediaWiki;
I only found literature on how to use it in Wikipedia.

How can one implement it in a non Wikipedia MediaWiki website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The install instructions are given at [Mediawiki.org, Extension:Gadgets](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets)

On your wiki you'll need to edit three pages, (except the format is a little messed up below):

1. MediaWiki:Gadgets-definition

   > - HotCat[ResourceLoader|rights=edit|default]|HotCat.js
2. MediaWiki:Gadget-HotCat

   > HotCat: Helps easily remove, change, and add categories to pages.'
3. MediaWiki:Gadget-HotCat.js

   > window.hotcat_translations_from_commons = true;
   >   mw.loader.load( '//commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Gadget-HotCat.js&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript' );

Comment: Did you manage to understand the "Usage" part right after the very simple "Installation" part? Because I didn't; I fell of in the right passage.

Comment: That usage section is very garbled. I've added more detail to my answer, I hope it helps. 1st edit should show * not a bullet.

Comment: So I just install the Gadgets extension and edit the three pages right afterwards by editing the three pages, and putting them codes I should find on the linked webpage, right?

Comment: As far as I can recall yes.

Comment: Fell off*, right->first*, saving them by editing the three pages* what stress can do... My neck hurts as well. Thanks,